# onclick not called html button

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm having trouble getting an onclick to fire. I've read the docs and several other posts,  but nothing seems to help. Any ideas? Thanks

```
    var inputDiv=document.createElement("div")
    inputDiv.className="form-grooup"

    var input=document.createElement("input")
    input.id="inputCommentField"
    input.class="form-contrrol"
    input.type="text"
    input.placeholder="Comments are anonymous"
    inputDiv.appendChild(input)

    actionDiv.appendChild(inputDiv)

    var commentButton=document.createElement("button")
    commentButton.id="sendButton"
    <!--    commentButton.type="button"-->
    commentButton.innerHTML="Reply"
    commentButton.onclick="comment();"
    inputDiv.appendChild(commentButton)

    var clearDiv=document.createElement("ul")
    actionDiv.appendChild(clearDiv)
    clearDiv.style="clear:both;"
```

definition of comment():

```
   function comment() {alert("you commented!")}
```

Comment: Use `commentButton.onclick=comment;`to

Answer (score 2):

When setting the `onclick` DOM element property, it takes a function reference, not a string. The HTML attribute takes a string -- this is separate.

```
commentButton.onclick=comment;
```

Like this, we pass the `comment` function by reference to `onclick`, which should work.

Also:

```
input.class="form-contrrol"
```

Should be `input.className`.

And

```
<!--    commentButton.type="button"-->
```

That is an HTML comment in JavaScript. Fix it.

```
//  commentButton.type="button"
```

Comment: Unfortanetly, this doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

- If you use `onclick` as a property

  You must assign a function reference:

  ```
  commentButton.onclick = comment;
  ```

  ```js
  function comment() {
    alert("you commented!");
  }

  var actionDiv = document.body,
    inputDiv = document.createElement("div");
  inputDiv.className = "form-grooup";

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.id = "inputCommentField";
  input.class = "form-contrrol";
  input.type = "text";
  input.placeholder = "Comments are anonymous";
  inputDiv.appendChild(input);

  actionDiv.appendChild(inputDiv);

  var commentButton = document.createElement("button");
  commentButton.id = "sendButton";

  commentButton.innerHTML = "Reply";
  commentButton.onclick = comment;
  inputDiv.appendChild(commentButton);

  var clearDiv = document.createElement("ul");
  actionDiv.appendChild(clearDiv);
  clearDiv.style = "clear:both;";
  ```
- If you use `onclick` as an attribute

  You must assign an string

  ```
  commentButton.setAttribute('onclick', "comment();");
  ```

  Not recommended. `comment` must be a global function.

  ```js
  function comment() {
    alert("you commented!");
  }

  var actionDiv = document.body,
    inputDiv = document.createElement("div");
  inputDiv.className = "form-grooup";

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.id = "inputCommentField";
  input.class = "form-contrrol";
  input.type = "text";
  input.placeholder = "Comments are anonymous";
  inputDiv.appendChild(input);

  actionDiv.appendChild(inputDiv);

  var commentButton = document.createElement("button");
  commentButton.id = "sendButton";

  commentButton.innerHTML = "Reply";
  commentButton.setAttribute('onclick', "comment()");
  inputDiv.appendChild(commentButton);

  var clearDiv = document.createElement("ul");
  actionDiv.appendChild(clearDiv);
  clearDiv.style = "clear:both;";
  ```
- If you use `addEventlistener`

  ```
  commentButton.addEventListener('click', comment);
  ```

  This is the most flexible way.

  ```js
  function comment() {
    alert("you commented!");
  }

  var actionDiv = document.body,
    inputDiv = document.createElement("div");
  inputDiv.className = "form-grooup";

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.id = "inputCommentField";
  input.class = "form-contrrol";
  input.type = "text";
  input.placeholder = "Comments are anonymous";
  inputDiv.appendChild(input);

  actionDiv.appendChild(inputDiv);

  var commentButton = document.createElement("button");
  commentButton.id = "sendButton";

  commentButton.innerHTML = "Reply";
  commentButton.addEventListener('click', comment);
  inputDiv.appendChild(commentButton);

  var clearDiv = document.createElement("ul");
  actionDiv.appendChild(clearDiv);
  clearDiv.style = "clear:both;";
  ```

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't fix it for me though

Answer (score -1):

You need to update the onclick to

```
commentButton.onclick = comment;
```

This should trigger the event